# Can't connect Laravel through SSL to MySQL. 'PDO::__construct(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, pdo, openssl, lumen

I am getting this error when I add the configuration to Laravel/Lumen to connect by ssl to the MySQL server.

```
2018-05-16 10:42:45] lumen.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'PDO::__construct(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto' in /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/Connector.php:56
```

I checked the installed php modules. It shows that `openssl` is installed with `php -m` and that `php-mysqlnd` is installed.

This is my configuration:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
        'strict'    => false,
        'options'   => array(
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/etc/ssl/certs/mysqlssl/key.pem',
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/ssl/certs/mysqlssl/cert.pem',
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/etc/ssl/certs/mysqlssl/ca-cert.pem',
    ),
```

And showing that mysql has ssl running:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out can't use localhost or it won't use TCP/IP and instead it will use unix sockets which don't use SSL.